# How to implement Facebook and Google login with a one logout button in android?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, google-plus

Hello Friends am beginner to android, Facebook and google plus login in a android application with use single logout button

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in, you could store a variable, with a value of 'facebook' or 'google'. When you click the log out button, check the value of the variable, then do whatever you need based on that.

Comment: Have u code? am beginner to android i don't know how to do that, please append

Answer (score 0):

First intialize Facbook SDK with the below line of code on your user welcome activity.

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Then, create a logoutUser() method that should be called on logout button click, like below;

```
private void logoutUser() {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut(); // this is to logout Facebook

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("finish", true); // if you are checking for this in your other Activities
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); // This will kill all current logged in activities
}
```

Call this one method through one logout button onClickListner n thats it.